# EntityFramework Query taking too long 1st execution

Tags: c#, .net, sql, linq, entity-framework

I have a process which runs exactly similar query twice(There reasons why) , First execution takes about 3 minutes.

The same query when executes second time it takes 4 seconds.

What can be causing this ?

This behavior is consistent, both times query is fired on exact number of rows and columns.

Comment: You really need to provide more information about the query for us to help, but it sounds like SQL is caching the data, and by the time you run it again the results have been removed from the cache.

Comment: Are you using the same context for both executions?

Comment: @pRimE Yes both are using same context .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to generate views for your entity using : [Entity Framework Power Tools Beta 3](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/72a60b14-1581-4b9b-89f2-846072eff19d)

It will generate pre-compiled views to improve performance.

Then you need to add the generated file ( EntityName.Views.cs ) to your project.

P.S: You need to generate views each time you modify your entity.